# Determination of threshold values to group variable in ranges

Tags: r, vba, optimization, time-series, solver

I have, let's say, 60 empirical realizations of PPR. My goal is to create PPR vector with average values of empirical PPR. This average values depend on what upper and lower limit of TTM i take - so I can take TTM from 60 to 1 and calculate average and in PPR vector put this one average number from row 1 to 60 or I can calculate average value of PPR from TTT >= 60 and TTM <= 30 and TTM > 30 and TTM <= 1 and these two calculated numbers put in my vector accordingly to TTM values. Finaly I want to obtain something like this on chart (x-axis is TTM, green line is my empirical PPR and black line is average based on significant changes during TTM). I want to write an algorithm which will help me find the best TTM thresholds to fit the best black line to green line.

[image]

[image]

```
TTM PPR
60 0,20%
59 0,16%
58 0,33%
57 0,58%
56 0,41%
...
10 1,15%
9 0,96%
8 0,88%
7 0,32%
6 0,16%
```

Can you please help me if you know any statistical method which might be applicable in this case or base idea for an algorithm which I could implement in VBA/R ?

I have used Solver and GRG Nonlinear** to deal with it but I believe that there is something more proper to be utilized.

** with Solver I had the problem that it found optimal solution - ok, but I re-run Solver and it found me new solution (with a little bit different values of TTM) and value of target function was lower that on first time (so, was the first solution really optimal ?)

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you want exactly. Do you want something like this? or something similar but with TTM column to be groupized into ranges and not exact percentages? [See the Image](https://www.screencast.com/t/x5slCDwybKj8)

Comment: Sorry that I was not precise enough, I edited post and added some graphs to show what I want to do

Comment: What I understood is that you want to have a parameter like a range and then calculate the average so that you can illustrate on the charts. I am not sure there is a method in statistics for this, but if you keep it simple you can write this easily with VBA. So assume range=3 meaning that you will take the average of every 3 record. The result would be like the image attached. Is this what you want? http://www.filedropper.com/capture_49

Comment: Thank you for your kind help but it is not exactly what I expect. I think that the case is more complex than you've presented. Please look on first image I attached - I see empirical realization (green line) and want to use this values in credit risk modelling, but I want to make these realizations simpler (or smoother), convert my empirical PPR vector to PPR vector with averages and make it more general and easier to applicable in model.

Comment: So, in the first picture I can see that, ok - from TTM = 61 to TTM = 14 my PPRs have similar values so I can approximate them with these average from TTM 61 - 14. But, from TTM >= 13 I see that my PPR are higher (in other words - represent different pattern to previous values). So TTM = 14 is my threshold but I determined it manually and want to determine it statistically (or quasi-statistically). To sum up - if want to find thresholds when my empirical realization change pattern.

Comment: So it is important to keep the order of TTM? and can you tell me what do TTM and PPR stand for?

Comment: Can you send me all of your data from 1 to 60 so that I can have a better sample data?

Comment: Yes, it is important to keep the order of TTM, TTM stands for Time to exposure's Maturity (in months) and PPR stands for partial prepayments (% of principal amount of loans that clients prepaid). I uploaded file with example data to my post above.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/04mfjrnygxctlgj/Data%20example%20Stack.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: This is a tough problem since it seems there is not a very standard statistic method to do such an analysis. I talked to a friend who is doing credit risk analysis and he mentioned the best way is to calculate the Mean and STDev and try to play with it so that you can fit it. This is not a VBA question right now and it is more how to define that criterion to find out when it should reset the calculation and treat the rest of data as a new set. I think the best move right now is to define a function that gets a TTM and breaks the calculations at that point

Comment: I will try to work on it, it is too much work though. You need to contact statisticians to see what criterion or function is defined in statistics that can determine that point of break for you, after that, it can be easily integrated into the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The next step would be including a method that can recognize the break points. I am sure you need to define two new parameters, one as the sensitivity and one as the minimum number of points in a sample to be accepted to be categorized as a section (between two break points including start and end point)

Please hit the checkmark next to this answer if you are happy with it.

You can download the Excel file from here:

http://www.filedropper.com/statisticspatternchange

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much ! Seems to be exactly what I want :)